# Python loop over iterator of list whose length is changed during the loop

Tags: python, loops

Let's say I would like to do the following: I have a list `l` and at each step I would like to check some condition between `l[i]` and `l[i+1]` and if it is satisfied, I will update `l[i]` based on `l[i+1]` and delete `l[i+1]`, then I will check condition between `l[i]` and former `l[i+2]` which is now new `l[i+1]` an so on. If at some step condition is not satisfied, I just do `i+=1`.

My implementation is as follows:

```
i = 0
while i < len(l): 
    if condition(l[i],l[i+1]):
        l[i] = update(l[i+1])
        del l[i+1]
    else:
        i += 1
```

Unfortunately, `len(l)` is only computed once, and when the `while` clause is checked, only `i` changes, not `len(l)`. Hence, at some moment if I deleted some elements I'd get an error of index being out of range. A similar issue appears when I insert new members of the list while iterating.

Comment: why not just create a new list as you go?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: if I'd like to insert something, while iterating over the old list I guess I won't be able to check conditions for inserted elements, will I?

Comment: Yes you can, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, from you description I think you want `del l[i+1]` and not `del l[i]`

It seems to me that you code does work, I think `len(l)` is being update on each pass as my example is able to stop when we want it to:

```
l = range(20)
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    print i, len(l), l
    if l[i] % 3 == 0:
        l[i] = -l[i+1]
        del l[i+1]
    else:
        i += 1
```

However, if your condition evaluates to true on the last step, then you will hit an index error, as in this example:

```
l = range(20)
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    print i, len(l), l
    if True:
        l[i] = -l[i+1]
        del l[i+1]
    else:
        i += 1
```

This is because you check `i < len(l)` and then try and access index `i+1`. What do you want to do once you're at the last element? Just stop? Then maybe you need this:

```
i = 0
while i + 1 < len(l): 
    if condition(l[i],l[i+1]):
        l[i] = update(l[i+1])
        del l[i+1]
    else:
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you have 2 ways to do that :

- use a second list as suggested by Padraic Cunningham :

  ```
  i = 0
  l2 = []
  while i < len(l) - 1: 
      if insert_condition_before(l[i]):
          l2.append(for_insert_beore(l[i])) # insert before l[i]
      if condition(l[i],l[i+1]):
          l[i] = update(l[i+1])
          i += 1 # skip l+1
      l2.append(l[i])
      i += 1
      if insert_condition_after(l[i]):
          l2.append(for_insert_after(l[i])) # insert after l[i]
  ```
- use a try-catch to determine end of array

  ```
  i = 0
  try:
      while True: 
          if insert_condition_before(l[i]):
              l.insert(for_insert_before(l[i])) # insert before l[i]
              i += 1
          if condition(l[i],l[i+1]):
              l[i] = update(l[i+1])
              del l[i+1]
          i += 1
          if insert_condition_after(l[i]):
              l.insert(for_insert_after(l[i])) # insert after l[i]
              i += 1 # if you do not want to analyse it again
  except IndexError:
      pass
  ```

Comment: There was a typo: I meant `del l[i+1]` in the code as well. Neither solution works in case of `insert` which I also described in the OP.